# Taking photo with API works on emulators and fails on real devices with: Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android, android-camera

I wrote a simple app based on this [blog post](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html#tutorial_cameraapi).
I changed the code a little to work on a Service and everything was OK, but when I test the app on real devices, when I call `camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));`, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
02-12 09:53:41.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21430):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
02-12 09:53:41.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21430):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:343)
02-12 09:53:41.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21430):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:303)
02-12 09:53:41.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21430):    at net.farayan.stillcamera.CameraService.onCreate(CameraService.java:37)
02-12 09:53:41.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2577)
02-12 09:53:41.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21430):    ... 10 more
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when camera is already in use or open. So there is a safe method provided Android Developer site. Which will first check if camera is open and then it will try to activate camera.

So add this method in your code, where you have Camera.open line.

write this

```
safeCameraOpen(camId);
```

instead of

```
camera.open();
```

and add this methods in your code.

```
 private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;

    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return qOpened;    
}


private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

It works. Mark my answer.

Comment: Camera opens successfully. The problem is when I call `camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));`. It takes more than usual and then throws an exception as I told in question.

Comment: can you post your handler so that I can know better. and also your complete logcat error. It will be easy to find out the error.

Comment: It never enters `onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)` method of `PhotoHandler` class. As I told this error happens in real devices but in emulator everything works well.

Comment: The camera on emulator may be too forgiving. When you switch to Service, do you still prepare a real visible SurfaceView for preview?

Comment: "Camera opens succesfully" -- the exception shown in the question is thrown from `Camera.open()`, so that doesn't make sense.  Are you trying to re-open the camera when it's already open (as this answer said)?

Comment: @ Ali Behzadian Nejad-- Now if you want the answer, I think you really need to show you handler method.